# Removing text from the Drupal interface

Tags: 7

I remember in Drupal 6 there was a module that did text substitution easily (from text that appeared anywhere in the interface). Does that exist in Drupal 7? I just want to remove the word "From" everywhere it appears on this Drupal commerce site: 
http://hum.homedns.org:8888/acmefilterbags2/product-category/featured-kits
thx!

UPDATE: I tried String Overrides, thought that would do it, but did not. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's not a text of Drupal Interface.

Add `.price_prefix { display: none }` to your theme's css file and it will **disappear**.

Comment: Thx so much herci! I could not find that text anywhere, and your fix is perfect (and safe).

Comment: An example of **K**eep **I**t **S**uper **S**imple, right?

Answer (score 1):

The css that @herci suggested was what I was going to suggest from your title but reading your description I doubt that would work as the likely of one word having it's own class is limited. So I can suggest three methods:

1. Use the development version of [Scanner](https://www.drupal.org/project/scanner) for D7; I haven't used it and it *could* be dangerous - so definitely back up your database!
2. Directly access your DB through cmd line (not all hosts offer that ability) or access your DB through PHPMyAdmin (again not all hosts offer that but *most* shared hosts do and if you have a private host you can usually install it yourself. Then browse the database and find which tables have 'from' that you want to remove - and then regex replace them. I don't actually recommend this as it has a **high chance of damaging your install** so if you do this definitely back it up.
3. Add a jQuery script: [jQuery ReplaceText](https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-replacetext) and add your own custom script something like this:

   `(function($) {
       $('#content p').replaceText( /\bfrom\b/gi, '' );
   }(jQuery))`

That will replace any instances of from in any paragraph elements inside an element with the id of content. You'll probably need to adjust that selector. This method has some advantages and disadvantages; it isn't actually changing your site, it just changes the appearance on load. So it can be slow but it is pretty *safe* unlike the other two methods.

Comment: thx for that Nick, but apparently in the theme that I am using (Omega Kickstart ecommerce) that one line of css from herci gets rid of the "From" with no side effects... like magic.